# Excel Crashes on Debug (and others)

Tags: windows, vba, excel, windows-update

I'm currently having a problem where Excel will crash on multiple occasions. The ones I've noticed so far are as follows:

- <strike>Debugging an error</strike>
- Deleting an entire function (Note: does not occur when only deleting contents)
- Other random developer type problems

My current analysis is that it was caused by the automatic Windows update ***KB3114564*** issued this morning. I have not been able to securely link the problem to this update, however.

<strike>I am going to try moving all my code to a new workbook, which will be a pain since it's a multi-module, multi-form project.</strike>

Please let me know if you have experienced any problems of the type today/before.

### Update 1:

Moving code to new workbook does not effect performance of Excel

### Update 2:

It appears that the problem I had with the debugger crashing had to do with trying to multiply a string by a double. This still shouldn't have caused the DEBUGGER to crash, but at least that problem is diagnosed.

Comment: What do you mean it crashes? Is there an error or does it just close?

Comment: @MatthewD as is the norm with "crashes", I press debug, all Excel windows haze up and the message "Microsoft Excel has stopped running - Windows is checking for a solution to the problem."

Comment: try reinstall a fresh excell from scratch (first uninstall it), it will be faster than waiting on microsoft to wake up.

Answer (score 0):

Tried several things, not sure which attempt fixed this.
I first  unregistered and registerd mscomctl.ocx and mscomct2.ocx in windows\syswow64
Still had a problem;  next I unchecked solver add-in in excel options.
this seemed to work.
I then checked recent KB updates and uninstalled KB3114564, re-added solver add-in and problem was resolved.
This does not keep KB3114564 from showing up again, but good enough for immediate emergency.